# Background Image that is covered instead of resizing when browser window resizes

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image

I'm wanting to be able to have a background that doesn't resize when the browser window does but rather looks like it is sliding the background behind its content. 
http://portal.office.com is a perfect example of the look I'm trying to get. I'm not sure what this effect is even called so I do not even know where to look or if this is done with mainly jQuery or CSS. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

***Edit***

As Stephan pointed out `background-size: cover` is close but that simply cuts off the image at the edge of the browser instead of the background being cut off by the other content when the window is resized.

Comment: `background-size: cover` should be all you need

Comment: Background-size: cover is close but when I resize the screen it just cuts off the image from the border of the browser as opposed to being cut off by the other elements on the page.

Comment: Here is the CSS on the `img` tag on that page - `width: 1580px; height:1202px; display: block; position: fixed;` It's not a background image, but a regular image.

Comment: Okay, so I could use a div in an image instead of a background image but I still don't understand how they create the effect of sliding that image behind the other content when the browser is resized. I'm guessing some jQuery?

Comment: Not jQuery, probably. If I was to guess, I would guess that they have the actual "content" in a div that is set to something like `width: 100%; max-width: 650px` or something similar, then they set the margin so that the whole thing only sits on the right side of the screen, `margin: 0 0 0 auto;`. Then, any image on the background of the page will stay fixed like that, but when the screen is resized the content div will just stay on the right side of the screen.

Comment: I'll try and whip something up to show what I mean in jsFiddle

Comment: Check this fiddle out: https://jsfiddle.net/9r0p0tjy/ . It has very similar functionality to that site.

Comment: Thanks @Aeolingamenfel that explains it perfectly, please add it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect, I will, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what Microsoft is doing on that page is setting some sort of background, then having the actual content div just take up a fixed width on the right side of the page.

**HTML**

```
<div class="Content">
    [your content goes here]
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
  background: /* your image goes here */;
  background-size: cover; /* makes sure image covers background, can be changed */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.Content
{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto; /* stay on right side if there is extra space */
  background: #fff;
}
```

The `width: 100%` and `max-width: 300px` says that at screen sizes larger than 300px, the content will only take up 300px of space, and will leave space for the image, but below that, will take up the full width.

I also set `min-height: 100vh` so that even if you don't have a lot of content, your content will fill the whole right side of the page.

**Example**

If you want to see an example, I put one up on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9r0p0tjy/).

Comment: This is great! I just have one, probably dumb question. When I try to put the .content div on the left instead of the right by changing the margin css to "0 auto 0 0" it looks fine but doesn't have the same functionality when I resize the browser. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Yeah, it has to do with how the browser figures out how to render the background image. By default, the background image is "attached" to the left side of the screen. You can re-set the position in that way using the `background-position: right (top|bottom|center)`. Here's a jsFiddle of the working left side functionality: https://jsfiddle.net/nc5dbq7v/ .

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft site is using js to resize the image. It seems like its only resizing when you resize the browser vertically not horizontally. The image will need to be fixed in order for it to work.

You could do background-size: cover, but it will keep resizing. You could also use media queries to stop the image from resizing and change background-size to auto and use media queries.

Another option like Aeolingamenfel said is to set a max-width.

This should give you a head start, but it will need a bit more logic. I'll leave that up to you ;)

```js
var w = 0;
var $window;
var $background;

function resize(e) {
  var _w = $window.width();
  
  if(w === _w) {
    $background.width(_w);
  }
  
  w = _w;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $window = $(window);
  $background = $('#background');
  $(window).resize(resize);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#background {
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.login-drawer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 70%;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <img src="https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/dbd5a2dd-6ybrougjmflxqw910ieyohr7wb4x4-yvoixrlaidmz4/appbranding/zeybopfwkgpwmcplgyvdjsbnpiq-j2ebveynzrvraxa/0/heroillustration?ts=635848522936289301" id="background" alt="" />
    <div class="login-drawer"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwPGrM

Comment: I actually like your answer as well but I am trying to avoid tampering with the JS at the moment. I might have to give your answer a go as well later on though.